# Ajax loaded ACF forms aren't initializing

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using he Advanced Custom Fields Pro WordPress plugin to create some post/page editing capabilities on the frontend of my website. I'm displaying blank forms by default and the user can select an existing post to edit which replaces the blank form with a pre-filled form.

In the edit form, Post Object and Relationship fields, and conditional logic are not being correctly "fixed up" with JS - the values are in the form correctly, but for example conditional logic rules don't apply (only show textA if checkA is checked.. by default checkA is unchecked so textA should be hidden, but is visible here). This all works correctly on non-ajax-loaded forms.

Here's my existing jQuery/ajax (`ajax_for_cms.js`):

```
var data = {
    'post_id'       : id,
    'post_type'     : type,
    'post_subtype'  : subtype,
    'form_id'       : formID,
    'action'        : 'get_form'
};

$.ajax({
    type : "post",
    dataType : "html",
    url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
    data : data,
    success: function(response) {
        $( theFormArea ).html( response );

        // This line is the likely problem.
        $(document).trigger('acf/setup_fields', $(formID) );
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        $( theFormArea ).html( "Sorry, something went wrong! Please let us know what happened." );
    }
})
```

The form is loaded onto the page properly with the correct formID in the rendered HTML, but Post Objects are blank (the correct input value is there, but blank to the user), things that should be shown/hidden due to conditional logic options are not (everything is shown), and relationship lists don't populate options.

There are no JS errors in the log. Forms loaded with the page originally (not through ajax) load as expected, and changing options on the affected fields causes them to right themselves (for example, checking and unchecking a checkbox causes the correct fields to show/hide) - the ajax-loaded forms just don't start out correctly. I have disabled all other plugins and have the same issue.

In a [forum post on ACF's website](http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/frontend-wysiwyg-problems/) I saw that the line `$(document).trigger('acf/setup_fields', $(formID) );` is intended to run all initializing JS on the form, but for me it doesn't appear to be doing anything.

I'm using ACF Pro v5.0.0, WordPress v3.8.3, and no additional plugins.

Any idea why `acf/setup_fields` isn't triggering, or if there's something else I need to do?

**Additional Code**

Here's the `get_form` action that's called via ajax, and the WordPress specific actions to make the ajax work (this all works correctly)  -

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'ajax_scripts' );
function ajax_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('cmsAJAX', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/ajax_for_cms.js', array('jquery','jquery-ui-button'));
    wp_localize_script( 'cmsAJAX', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
}
add_action("wp_ajax_get_form", "get_form");

function get_form() {
    $id = $_POST['post_id'];
    $type = $_POST['post_type'];
    $subtype = $_POST['post_subtype'];
    $form_id = $_POST['form_id'];

    acf_form( getFormAttrs($type, $id, $subtype, $form_id) );

    // I tried the JS trigger here as well with the same, non-working results
    ?>
    <script>
        (function($) {
            $(document).trigger('acf/setup_fields', $("<?php echo "#".$form_id; ?>") );
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php

    die();
}
```

The HTML generated is a normal `<form>` element, with a bunch of ACF-specific classes/data fields/ etc. The important part is that the form's id matches the formId that's sent through ajax and into the setup_fields trigger.

Comment: I see that your POST has no action, is that normal with that plugin? In general in Wordpress you have to first add the action, and the use that action in the AJAX calls. [Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Comment: @TomásCot it does have (and require) an action actually, I have it inside the `data` variable. I've added it to my code above.

Comment: Do you have more code related to this issue? If you do please add it to the question

Comment: @TomásCot There's really not more to the code. `response` returns a `<form id='formId'>..</form>` with the (correct) post info pre-filled form editing and I have it loading into the correct area on my page (`theFormArea`). The issue is that the form that's been loaded isn't having the initializing JS run on it - `$(document).trigger('acf/setup_fields', $(formID) );` is supposed to do that, I think? It's not very clearly documented though.

Comment: @TomásCot I've added the PHP function and WordPress hooks to call the function using WP's built-in ajax handler. This part all seems to work correctly - the form is displayed with the correct post's information pre-filled at least.